# Link to webpage from my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder

How do I set up a label in Interface Builder to (when clicked) send the user to a website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What PengOne said. Or progammatically something like this:

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"obliquely.org.uk" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[button titleLabel] setFont: [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 16.0]];
[[button titleLabel] setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
[button setTitleColor: [UIColor lightGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor: [UIColor darkGrayColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setFrame: CGRectMake (100.0, 100.0, 140.0, 16.0 + 4.0)
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(appWebsite) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This gives a gray link that goes darker when the user taps on it. Doing it programmatically can be helpful if you want to position the link carefully and differently depending on orientation / whether you are on iPad or iPhone /  other stuff happening on screen. (Though, of course, you can still use IB and just adjust the frame.)

And then add a method a bit like this:

```
- (void) appWebsite;
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://obliquely.org.uk/blog/app"]];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a button,

```
 IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

and declare an action

```
-(IBAction)goToWebSite;
```

Set the button target to the action in the IB. In the .m file, define the action:

```
    -(IBAction)goToWebSite {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mywebpage.com"]];          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a UITextView to hold the URL text. It will automatically be clickable and will take the user there when clicked. You can give the textView a clear background so it looks just like a label or whatever you want.